# Internet Access over Huawei 4G+ Router using Cisco 3750 L3 Switch

Tags: cisco

We have

a) 2 Huawei 4G+ (Wired and Wireless) Internet Routers

b) 1 Cisco Catalyst 3750 Switch

c) 2 Department VLANs: VLAN 10 (SVI: 192.168.10.254) & VLAN 11 (SVI : 192.168.11.254)

Our requirement is to access internet using these 2 Routers per VLAN's,If i would say more clear,VLAN 10 Users should connect Huawei Router1 for accessing the internet and VLAN 11 Users should Connect Huawei Router 2 for the internet access.Also intervlan routing should be enabled to ping each VLAN's.And DHCP for each VLAN network need to configured on Cisco Switch.

1) can we configure static routes based on VLAN ID to redirect the internet traffic ?

2) When creating DHCP pool for each VLAN,what should be the Default Gateway and DNS to access internet Service?

3) can we configure Wireless users connected to the Huwaei Routers to get the DHCP lease from Cisco Switch based on the VLAN's Network Pool?

NOTE : Both Huawei Routers comes with Default IP 192.168.8.1 as Default Gateway, DHCP and DNS

anyone please give a sample configuration to accomplish this Task

Answer (score 1):

Broadly speaking you would configure the Huawei routers to be gateways on each VLAN and send routed traffic to them, but with the information you have given that is about as much as I can tell you.

Comment: Hello Simon,Appreciate your feedback, But if we set huawei routers IP as the DG for each vlan,how can we enable intervlan routing? VLAN 10 cannot communicate with VLAN 11 right ?

Comment: I assume that the switch is also acting as a router in this case. If it isn't you are going to have to apply routing on the connected devices. You could *probably* use the Huawei routers as network routers as they run OpenWRT or similar but that's probably not their best use. Everything else you say is pretty much correct as long as the switch has the capability to do it.